# At KOAK, how can I get a passenger from the GA terminal to the commercial terminal?

Tags: landing, landing-fees

I want to land at the GA side of [Oakland International (KOAK)](https://www.aopa.org/destinations/airports/KOAK/details) in order to drop my passenger off for a commercial flight from the main terminal. I was told by a local guy that they do not allow a taxi on B over to the main terminal so I would need to park on the GA side and grab a shuttle/crew car/Uber over to the main terminal. I've contacted two FBO's and they tell me of about $50 in fees just to stop in. Has anyone done this and what is the best way?

Answer (score 3):

This is a specific question but I think my advice applies to most FBOs.
I fly out of OAK and your best bet is to try signature. Buy some fuel, ask nicely and if they aren't too busy they might be able to accommodate you. 
They have given me rides on the ramp before when my usual gate was closed due to a power outage.

If not, then call a rideshare/cab

Answer (score 2):

I got a hold of two FBO's on the field.  Evidently they were trying to negotiate with the port authority regarding fees for small single engine aircraft to no avail.  Landing fees are currently $49 and can not be waived with fuel purchase.  The FBO's also charge a parking fee and a handling fee which are significant but can be waived or reduced with fuel purchase.